# Querying the number of folders on my Google Drive

Tags: c#-4.0, google-drive-api

I currently loop through the list of google drive folders and return them all with no issues using the following...

```
FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = drive.Files.List();
listRequest.Q = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'";
listRequest.PageSize = 1000;
listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(mimeType, id, name, parents)";
FileList listResults = null;

do
{
    if (taskInfo.Cancel.IsCancellationRequested) return;

    listResults = listRequest.Execute();
    IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> gObjects = listResults.Files;

    if (gObjects != null && gObjects.Count > 0)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Got folder batch of " + gObjects.Count + " folders.");
    }
} while (listRequest.PageToken != null);
```

The only issue I have is I would really like to know if there was a query of some type I could use to ONLY return the COUNT of folders on my Google Drive BEFORE I start listing them in a batch.  Is there one?

Comment: I also couldn't find anything in the documention to do COUNT operation and end up doing exactly as you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Google Drive API [Search functionality](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters#operators). So if you're looking for folders you can try:

`mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'` then perform a count.

Comment: That will not work.  That does the same thing as list does (this is EXACTLY what I have in my question)...  It will generate pages of about 490 objects at a time.  Then you have to call it again with the page token to continue getting the results.  I'm looking for a way to return the count, NOT the objects.